# Notice: Undefined offset: -1 phpOCR

Tags: php, ocr

Hi I need to use **phpOCR** 'package' for 'extract the text' from an image. I downloaded the package from here 
**http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpocr/** and added to local server. but when I called the index file I only ger
t this **error message**,

> Notice: Undefined offset: -1 in C:\wamp\www\phpOCR\index.php on line 189

It would be great if somone can help...

This is the index file,

```
<?php
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");    // Date in the past
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); 
                                                         // always modified
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");  // HTTP/1.1
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");                          // HTTP/1.0




    /**************************************************************************************************/
    function get_col($array, $num) { //extracts collon from two-dimensional array
    /**************************************************************************************************/
        return $array[$num];
    }
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    function get_row($array, $num) { //extracts row from two-dimensional array
    /**************************************************************************************************/
        $retmas = Array();
            $size_x = sizeof($array);
            for($x=0;$x<$size_x;$x++) {
                $retmas[] = $array[$x][$num];
            }
        return $retmas;
    }

    /**************************************************************************************************/
    function get_dispersion($array, $bg) { //gets dispersion from one-dimensional array using average $bg
    /**************************************************************************************************/

        $size = sizeof($array);
        if ($size>0) {
            $dispersion = 0.0;
            for($c=0;$c<$size;$c++) {
                $val = $bg-$array[$c];
                $dispersion+=$val*$val;
            }
            return $dispersion;
        }
        else {
            echo "error!!!!!!!!!!";
            return -1;
        }
    }
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    function parse_letters($row, $max_x, $max_y, $bg) {
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    global $conf;
        $min_dispersion = $conf['letters_min_dispersion'];
        $letter = -1;
        $adding = false;
        for($x=0;$x<=$max_x;$x++) {
            $col = get_row($row, $x);
            $dispersion = get_dispersion($col, $bg);
            if ($dispersion > $min_dispersion) {
                if ($adding==false)
                    $letter++;
                $letters[$letter][]=$col;
                $adding = true;
            }
            else {
                    $adding = false;
            }
        }
        $size = sizeof($letters);
        for($c=0;$c<$size;$c++)
            $letters[$c] = transpon($letters[$c]);
        return $letters;
    }
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    function parse_word_lines($mas, $max_x, $max_y, $bg) {
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    global $conf;
        $min_dispersion = $conf['word_lines_min_dispersion'];
        $line = -1;
        $adding = false;
        for($y=0;$y<=$max_y;$y++) {
            $row = get_row($mas, $y);
            $dispersion = get_dispersion($row, $bg);

            if ($dispersion > $min_dispersion) {
                if ($adding==false)
                    $line++;
                $lines[$line][]=$row;
                $adding = true;
            }
            else {
                    $adding = false;
            }
        }
        return $lines;
    }
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    function test_char_verbose($letter, $template_index,$bg) {
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    global $char_mas;
    global $max_color;

    $size = $char_mas[$template_index]['size'];
    $char = $char_mas[$template_index]['char'];

        $height=sizeof($letter);
        $width=sizeof($letter[0]);
        $sum = 0;
        $x_diff = $size[0]/$width;
        $y_diff = $size[1]/$height;
        $color_diff = 255/$max_color;

        echo "<pre>";
        for($y=0;$y<$height;$y++) {
            echo "<br>";
            for($x=0;$x<$width;$x++) {
                    $x_rel = ceil($x*$x_diff); //translate $x, $y to relative coords
                    $y_rel = ceil($y*$y_diff);
                $val = diff_char($letter, $char,$x_diff,$y_diff, $x,$y,$bg);
                $sum+= $val;

                if ($letter[$y][$x]!=$char[$y_rel][$x_rel]) {
                    echo '<font color="red">'.$letter[$y][$x].'-'.$char[$y_rel][$x_rel]."</font>&nbsp;";
                }else {
                    echo $letter[$y][$x].'-'.$char[$y_rel][$x_rel]."</font>&nbsp;";
                }
                //echo ($letter[$y][$x]*$color_diff).':'.$char[$y_rel][$x_rel]."\t";

            }
        }
        echo "</pre>";
        return $sum;
    }
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    function test_chars($letter,$bg,$char_mas,$max_color) {
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    //global $char_mas;
    //global $max_color;

        $lib_size = sizeof($char_mas);
        $min_disp = -1;
        for($c=0; $c<$lib_size;$c++) {
            $disp = test_char($letter, $c, $bg,$char_mas,$max_color);
            //echo 'AT:'.$c.':'.$disp.'<br>';
            if (($disp<$min_disp)||($min_disp==-1)) {
                $min_disp = $disp;
                $min_disp_at = $c;
            }
        }
        //$disp = test_char_verbose($letter, $min_disp_at,$bg);
        return Array($min_disp,$min_disp_at);
        //return $min_disp_at;
    }

    /**************************************************************************************************/
    function test_char($letter, $template_index,$bg,$char_mas,$max_color) {
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    //global $char_mas;
    //global $max_color;

    $size = $char_mas[$template_index]['size'];
    $char = $char_mas[$template_index]['char'];

        $height=sizeof($letter);
        $width=sizeof($letter[0]);
        $sum = 0;
        $color_diff = 255/$max_color;
        $x_diff = $size[0]/$width;
        $y_diff = $size[1]/$height;

        for($y=0;$y<$height;$y++) {
            for($x=0;$x<$width;$x++) {
                $sum+= diff_char($letter, $char,$x_diff,$y_diff, $x,$y, $bg);
            }
        }
        return $sum;
    }
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    function diff_char($l_mas, $c_mas,$x_diff,$y_diff, $x,$y, $bg) { //returns dispersion of one pixel in letter's coord. system
    /**************************************************************************************************/

        global $color_diff;

        $x_rel = ceil($x*$x_diff); //translate $x, $y to relative coords
        $y_rel = ceil($y*$y_diff);
        $char_val = $c_mas[$y_rel+1][$x_rel]+$c_mas[$y_rel-1][$x_rel]+$c_mas[$y_rel][$x_rel+1]+$c_mas[$y_rel][$x_rel-1];
        $char_val = $char_val/4;
        //echo '['.($l_mas[$y][$x]*$color_diff)-$c_mas[$y_rel][$x_rel])).']';
        $val_m[] = abs(($l_mas[$y][$x])-($c_mas[$y_rel][$x_rel]));

        $val_m[] = abs(($l_mas[$y][$x])-($c_mas[$y_rel+1][$x_rel]));
        $val_m[] = abs(($l_mas[$y][$x])-($c_mas[$y_rel-1][$x_rel]));
        $val_m[] = abs(($l_mas[$y][$x])-($c_mas[$y_rel][$x_rel+1]));
        $val_m[] = abs(($l_mas[$y][$x])-($c_mas[$y_rel][$x_rel-1]));

        $val_m[] = abs(($l_mas[$y][$x])-($c_mas[$y_rel+1][$x_rel+1]));
        $val_m[] = abs(($l_mas[$y][$x])-($c_mas[$y_rel-1][$x_rel-1]));
        $val_m[] = abs(($l_mas[$y][$x])-($c_mas[$y_rel+1][$x_rel-1]));
        $val_m[] = abs(($l_mas[$y][$x])-($c_mas[$y_rel-1][$x_rel+1]));

        $val = min($val_m);
        return $val*$val*$val*$val*$val;
    }

    function getmicrotime(){ 
        $tmp = explode(" ",microtime());
        return ((float)$tmp[0] + (float)$tmp[1]); 
        } 

    /**************************************************************************************************/
    function print_matrix($letter) {
    /**************************************************************************************************/
        $ret = '';
        foreach($letter as $row) {
            $ret.= "\n";
            foreach($row as $pixel) {
                    $ret.= $pixel." ";
            }
        }
        return $ret;
    }

    /**************************************************************************************************/
    function print_array($letter,$bg) {
    /**************************************************************************************************/
        $ret = '';
        $letter_size = sizeof($letter);
        $c=1;
    $ret.= "\n\t".'Array("char"=>Array('."\n";
        foreach($letter as $row) {
            $ret.= "\t\tArray(";
            $row_size= sizeof($row);
            $c1=1;
            foreach($row as $pixel) {
                $ret.= $pixel;
                if (($row_size-$c1)!=0)
                    $ret.= ",";
                $c1++;
            }

            if (($letter_size-$c)!=0)
                $ret.= "),\n";
            else
                $ret.= ")\n";

            $c++;
        }
    $ret.= "\t\t".'), "size"=>Array('.($c1-1).','.($c-1)."))";

        return $ret;
    }
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    function flatten_matrix($letter, $bg, $max_color) { //replaces background with 0 and 1 otherwice
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    //global $max_color;

        $y_size = sizeof($letter);
        $x_size = sizeof($letter[0]);

        for($c=0;$c<$y_size;$c++) {
            for($c1=0;$c1<$x_size;$c1++) {
                    $tmp_val = (abs($bg-$letter[$c][$c1])/$max_color)*3;
                    $letter[$c][$c1]=round($tmp_val*$tmp_val);
            }
        }
        return $letter;
    }
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    function write_template($filename) { //returns template
    /**************************************************************************************************/
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Connection: close");

        $image_data=extract_mas($filename);

        $max_x      = $image_data['imagewidth']-1;
        $max_y      = $image_data['imageheight']-1;
        $mas        = $image_data['mas'];
        $max_color  = $image_data['max_color'];
        $bg         = $image_data['bg'];


        $lines = parse_word_lines($mas, $max_x, $max_y, $bg);
        $ret = '';
        $ret.= '<?php';
        foreach($lines as $word_line) {
            $letters = parse_letters($word_line, $max_x, $max_y, $bg);
            $ret.="\n".'$'.'char_global_mas[] = Array (';
            $letters_size = sizeof($letters);
            $c = 1;
            foreach($letters as $letter) {
                $letter = flatten_matrix($letter,$bg,$max_color);
                $ret.= print_array($letter,$bg);
                if (($letters_size-$c)!=0)
                    $ret.=',';
                $c++;
            }
            $ret.="\n".');'."\n";
        }
        $ret.= '?>';
        return $ret;

    }
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    function transpon($mas) { //returns a tronsponed matrix
    /**************************************************************************************************/
        $retmas = Array();
        foreach($mas as $row) {
            $size = sizeof($row);
            for($c=0;$c<$size;$c++) {
                $retmas[]= get_row($mas, $c);
            }
            return $retmas; //nasty should think of cleaner solution
        }
        return $retmas;
    }
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    function extract_mas($filename) { //returns a two dimensional matrix with parsed data
    /**************************************************************************************************/
        $imagehw = @GetImageSize($filename) or die('ERROR occured while trying to stat image file: '.$filename); 
        $imagewidth = $imagehw[0]; 
        $imageheight = $imagehw[1]; 
        $imagetype = $imagehw[2];

        if($imagetype==1) {         //GIF

    //  Uncoment next three lines if you want to use GIF+gif2png. Insecure!!!! anything could be passed to shell.   
    //      $ret = `cat $filename|/usr/local/bin/gif2png`;
    //      $filename = 'noname.png';
    //      $im = imagecreatefrompng($filename);

    //btw if anyone has a good idea how to integrate other image formats please let me know

            echo 'ERROR: GIF support is not in by default! If you really want to enable this check parse_image function in index.php';
            exit(0);
        }
        elseif($imagetype==2) {     //JPG
            $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
        }
        elseif($imagetype==3) {     //PNG
            $im = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
        }
        else {
            echo 'ERROR:Unsuported image type code:'.$imagetype.'. phpOCR only supports PNG, JPG, GIF(see doc.)';
            exit(0);
        }


        $max_color=-1;
        for($y=0;$y<$imageheight;$y++) {
            for($x=0;$x<$imagewidth;$x++) {
                $rgb = ImageColorAt($im, $x, $y);
                if($rgb>$max_color) $max_color=$rgb;
                $mas[$x][$y] = $rgb;
            }
        }
        $bg = $mas[0][0];       //we detect background by checking the first top pixel

    return Array('mas'=>$mas,'max_color'=>$max_color,'imagewidth'=>$imagewidth,'imageheight'=>$imageheight,'bg'=>$bg);
    }
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    function parse_image($filename,$font_file) { //returns a two dimensional matrix with parsed data
    /**************************************************************************************************/

        $image_data=extract_mas($filename);

        $max_x      = $image_data['imagewidth']-1;
        $max_y      = $image_data['imageheight']-1;
        $mas        = $image_data['mas'];
        $max_color  = $image_data['max_color'];
        $bg         = $image_data['bg'];

        $lines = parse_word_lines($mas, $max_x, $max_y, $bg);
        require($font_file);        //font library
        $line_index=0;
        foreach($lines as $word_line) {
            //echo "&lt;LINE&gt;\n";
            $letters = parse_letters($word_line, $max_x, $max_y, $bg);
            //echo "<br>";
            $letter_index=0;
            if (sizeof($char_global_mas)>1) echo 'WARNING!!! The output will contain only result of the second font<br>';
            foreach($char_global_mas as $char_mas) {    //for testing purposes. tests w different fonts
                foreach($letters as $letter) {
                    $letter = flatten_matrix($letter,$bg,$max_color); //global $letter
                        $tmp = test_chars($letter,$bg,$char_mas,$max_color);
                        $disp = $tmp[0];    //relative number of trust
                        $num = $tmp[1];     //parsed number
                        $retmas[$line_index][$letter_index]=Array($num,$disp);
                        //echo '[[[['.$num.']]]]';
                        $letter_index++;
                }
            }
            $line_index++;
        }
        return $retmas;
    }
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    //MAIN
    /**************************************************************************************************/

    //If you create a new font include file replace char_inc_6.php with your own
    $conf['font_file']                  = 'char_inc_6.php';

    //The defoult image that gets parsed when no parameter filename is given
    $conf['default_image']              = 'tmp1.png';

    //The default output format. You can chose from xml,html,plain,template.
    $conf['default_output_format']      = 'html';

    //You shold probably not need to change thees
    $conf['word_lines_min_dispersion']  = 0;
    $conf['letters_min_dispersion']     = 0;


    $out=isset($_REQUEST['out'])?$_REQUEST['out']:$conf['default_output_format'];
    $filename = isset($_REQUEST['filename'])?$_REQUEST['filename']:$conf['default_image'];


    if ($filename == 'upload') {
        $filename = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    }


    $time_start = getmicrotime();
    if($out!='template') {

        //*******************************************************
        //This is the main function. Format of the output array is $retmas[$line_number][$letter_number][$type]
        //where $type is 0 for digit and 1 for relative closeness
        $retmas = parse_image($filename,$conf['font_file']);
        //*******************************************************

        $time = getmicrotime() - $time_start;   //execution time
    }

    if($out=='xml')
        echo print_output_xml($retmas,$filename,$time);
    elseif ($out=='html')
        echo print_output_html($retmas,$filename,$time);
    elseif ($out=='plain')
        echo print_output_plain($retmas);
    elseif ($out=='template')
        echo write_template($filename); //this is different from xml,html or plain

    /**************************************************************************************************/
    function print_output_html($retmas,$filename,$time) {
    /**************************************************************************************************/
        $ret = '';
        $ret.='<html>';
        $ret.='<body>';
        $ret.='<center>';
        $ret.='<table border=0>';
        $ret.='<tr><td valign="top" ><center><font size="+3">phpOCR</font></center></td><td></td></tr>';

        $ret.='<tr><td valign="top">Original image:</td><td><img src="'.$filename.'"></td></tr>';
        //$ret.='<p class="f">';

        $ret.='<tr><td valign="top">Line_count:</td><td>'.sizeof($retmas).'</td></tr>';
        $ret.='<tr><td valign="top">Parsed content:</td><td>';
        foreach($retmas as $line) {
            foreach($line as $digit) {
                $ret.='<font size="+2"><B>'.$digit[0].'</B></font>('.$digit[1].')';
            }
            $ret.='<br>';
        }
        $ret.='</td></tr>';
        $ret.='<tr><td>Time consumed:</td><td>'.$time.'s</td></tr>';
        $ret.='<tr><td></td><td>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;</td></tr>';

        $ret.='<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php" method="post">';
        $ret.='<tr><td colspan=2>';
        $ret.='<input type="hidden" name="filename" value="upload">';
        $ret.='Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file">';
        $ret.=', output type:<SELECT NAME="out"><option value="html">html<option value="plain">plain<option value="xml">xml<option value="template">template</SELECT>';
        $ret.='<input type="submit" value="Parse">';
        $ret.='</td></tr>';
        $ret.='</form>';

        $ret.='<tr><td colspan=2>or</td></tr>';

        $ret.='<tr><td colspan=2>';
        $ret.='<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php" method="post">';
        $ret.='Type in URL: <input name="filename" type="text" value="http://">';
        $ret.=', output type:<SELECT NAME="out"><option value="html">html<option value="plain">plain<option value="xml">xml<option value="template">template</SELECT>';
        $ret.='<input type="submit" value="Parse">';
        $ret.='</td></tr>';
        $ret.='</form>';

        $ret.='<tr><td colspan=2>or</td></tr>';

        $ret.='<tr><td colspan=2>';
        $ret.='<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php" method="post">';
        $ret.='Use default image.';
        $ret.=' output type:<SELECT NAME="out"><option value="html">html<option value="plain">plain<option value="xml">xml<option value="template">template</SELECT>';
        $ret.='<input type="submit" value="Parse">';
        $ret.='</form>';
        $ret.='</td></tr>';

        $ret.='<tr><td></td><td>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;</td></tr>';

        $ret.='<tr><td colspan=2>';
        $ret.='<B>Note:</B> For use in outomated scripts try something like:<br>';
        $ret.='curl -s -o out1.txt http://YOUR_URL/index.php?out=plain&filename=http://REMOTE_URL/image.png<br>';
        $ret.='or better just hack the index.php :)';
        $ret.='</td></tr></table>';
        $ret.='</center>';
        $ret.='</body>';
        $ret.='</html>';
        return $ret;
    }
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    function print_output_plain($retmas) {
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Connection: close");

        $ret = '';
        foreach($retmas as $line) {
            foreach($line as $digit) {
                $ret.=$digit[0];
            }
            $ret.="\n";
        }
    return substr($ret,0,strlen($ret)-1);
    }
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    function print_output_xml($retmas,$filename,$time) {
    /**************************************************************************************************/
    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    header("Connection: close");
        $ret.='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>'."\n\n";

        $ret.='<output time="'.$time.'">'."\n";
        $ret.="\t".'<line_count>'.sizeof($retmas).'</line_count>'."\n";

        for($c=0;$c<sizeof($retmas);$c++) {
            $ret.="\t".'<line number="'.($c+1).'">'."\n";
            $ret.="\t\t".'<digit_count>'.sizeof($retmas[$c]).'</digit_count>'."\n";
            for($c1=0;$c1<sizeof($retmas[$c]);$c1++) {
                $ret.="\t\t".'<digit number="'.($c1+1).'">'."\n";
                    $ret.="\t\t\t".'<value>'.$retmas[$c][$c1][0].'</value>'."\n";
                    $ret.="\t\t\t".'<closeness>'.$retmas[$c][$c1][1].'</closeness>'."\n";
                $ret.="\t\t".'</digit>'."\n";
            }
            $ret.="\t".'</line>'."\n";
        }
        $ret.='</output>'."\n";

    return $ret;
    }
?>
```

Comment: you must need to check your loop or share the code here.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: I added the index file code as requested